# How to batch a pdo loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am completely stumped how to do this. I want to perform a function per batch of 100 mysql results.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT count(user) AS cnt, user FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($row AS $row) {
    $user .= $row['user'];
}

function($user);
```

The trouble is I can't figure out how to stop the loop each 100, perform the function, then continue again until there are no more results.

Comment: what function you want to perform and what's the point of this particular query? at the moment it won't get you nor 100 nor even 10 results

Comment: @JayBlanchard no it doesn't, it returns every $row['user']; from a table named table

Comment: My bad, I missed that. `cnt` will be the same for every row returned. You need to accumulate a count as you loop through and each time it hits the hundred (determined by using mod) you would fire your function.

Comment: Hey @YourCommonSense - how did you determine this to be a duplicate? I believe your algorithm is 'off'

Comment: The reason for $row['cnt'] was I was trying to attempt a for loop using the cnt as the max number.

Comment: you trying to do some form of pagination? if not, what's it for? @Bruce

Comment: You can count the number of rows returned without doing it in the query. `$num_rows = count($row);` right after `$row = $stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: I am trying to use the google safebrowsing API and it has a limit of sending 500 url's per post. So I am trying to break the posts up into batch files.

Comment: that may prove to be relevant to the question then. If not, then you've an answer below; see that. You better test that first and completely.

Comment: I really have tried more ways than I can count but I suppose I do have a solution, though not exactly what I was hoping for. First I need to get to total row count - $row['cnt']; Then I need to divide that by 100 to determine how many loops to perform. Then I need to get the id of the first row and multiple that by 100 to get the first stopping point. Then I need to set the stopping and starting point by multiplying the first row by 100.... and then subsequently each starting row by 100 also, until I have reached the total. Kind of messy it seems but I guess I work with what I am given :P

Comment: and still thats wrong also, that assumes id's never skip a number.

Comment: That is why I recommended the `mod()` function. You will not have to worry about skipped ID's. The answer below also doesn't care about ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt=$db->query("SELECT user FROM table");
$i = 1;
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $user .= $row['user'];
    if ($i++ == 100) {
        function($user);
        $i = 1;
    }
}
function($user);
```

Comment: so, why'd you go and close the question in the first place with no evidence to support it and just now post an answer, and didn't even answer to Jay's comment. I take it that Jay's not part of your league?

Comment: I was actually thinking something very similiar only instead of if ($i++ == 100) I was thinking if ($i != $row['cnt']) { $i = $i + 100; }

Comment: This is actually beautiful. I didn't get it at first! So set a counter. Then each loop increase the counter, then check if the loop is at the desired interval - if so perform function and reset counter. As is typically the case, the foreach will exit when no more result so no need to worry about row counts at all. :)